# SQL query to sum the sales and number of orders from a client from two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was able to write the query I wanted for one table:

```
    DECLARE @date1 AS DATETIME
      , @date2 AS DATETIME

SET @date1 = '12/1/2018'
SET @date2 = '1/1/2019'

SELECT
    cl.BusinessName
    ,MAX(fn.FirstName) as Contact
    ,MAX(em.Email) as Email
    ,OT.numOrders
    ,OT.Total
FROM Orders ord
JOIN Clients cl on ord.ClientID = cl.RID
JOIN Staffs fn on ord.StaffID = fn.RID
JOIN Staffs em on ord.StaffID = em.RID
JOIN (SELECT ClientId,
            SUM(OrderTotal + Gratuity + Tax) as Total,
            COUNT(Distinct EventDateTime) as numOrders
     FROM Orders
     WHERE NOT OrderStatus=6
     GROUP BY ClientId) OT ON Ord.ClientId = OT.ClientId
WHERE   NOT OrderStatus = 6 
    AND NOT cl.BusinessName = 'Wildcard' 
    AND isdraft = 0 
    AND entydate between @date1 and @Date2 
GROUP BY cl.BusinessName
        ,OT.numOrders
        ,OT.Total
```

It outputs something like this:

```
ClientName1 Staff1  Email1  NumOrders   $18750.7763
```

I have another table with orders called (ORDERS2) and I'd like to sum the number of orders from those clients and the sales of those clients to this query. So it would look like this

```
ClientName1 Staff1  Email1  NumOrders + NumOrders from ClientName1 from ORDERS2 $18750.7763 + Sales from ClientName1 from ORDERS2
```

Comment: Which sql you are using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: first of all, you use 2 join for staff which one is enough, the second one if I understand correctly you have same order table which you saved it order2, if it is true you have to use exactly subquery join that you wrote for your order

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another `sub-query` to get ORDERS2 details. Check this query and update with your needs:

```
SET @date1 = '12/1/2018'
SET @date2 = '1/1/2019'

SELECT
    cl.BusinessName
    ,MAX(fn.FirstName) as Contact
    ,MAX(em.Email) as Email
    ,OT.numOrders
    ,OT.Total
    ,ISNULL(OT.numOrders,0)+ISNULL(OT2.numOrders,0) [Total Numbers Of O + O2]
    ,ISNULL(OT.Total,0)+ISNULL(OT2.Total,0) [Total Of O + O2]
FROM Orders ord
JOIN Clients cl on ord.ClientID = cl.RID
JOIN Staffs fn on ord.StaffID = fn.RID
JOIN Staffs em on ord.StaffID = em.RID
JOIN (SELECT ClientId,
            SUM(OrderTotal + Gratuity + Tax) as Total,
            COUNT(Distinct EventDateTime) as numOrders
     FROM Orders
     WHERE NOT OrderStatus=6
     GROUP BY ClientId) OT ON Ord.ClientId = OT.ClientId

--GET ORDERS2 DETAIL
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ClientId,
            SUM(OrderTotal + Gratuity + Tax) as Total,
            COUNT(Distinct EventDateTime) as numOrders
     FROM ORDERS2
     WHERE NOT OrderStatus=6
     GROUP BY ClientId) OT2 ON Ord.ClientId = OT2.ClientId

WHERE   NOT OrderStatus = 6 
    AND NOT cl.BusinessName = 'Wildcard' 
    AND isdraft = 0 
    AND entydate between @date1 and @Date2 
GROUP BY cl.BusinessName
        ,OT.numOrders
        ,OT.Total
```